# Validate dynamically generated input box with dynamic ID and name

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic-variables

I have a button that adds two input field onclick. Below is the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" id="additem">
Click here to add Items</button>
<form>
<div id="inputboxes"></div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and JQuery is

```
var i = 1,
    j = 1,
    k = 1,
    l = 1;
$("#additem").click(function () {
    $("#inputboxes").append("<div class='form-group'><input type='text' id='iname" +
        (j++) +
        "' name='iname" +
        (i++) +
        "' class='form-control'  placeholder='Enter Item Name' required='required'/></div> " +
        "<div class='form-group'><input type='text' id='iprice" +
        (k++) +
        "'   name='iprice" +
        (l++) +
        "' class='form-control'  placeholder='Enter Item Price' required='required'/></div>");
})
```

How can i validate these dynamically added input boxes for empty and correct values on submitting the form?

Comment: What did you try..? what do you mean by correct values..? what is the problem you're facing..?

Comment: i tried validating by having 'iname' and 'iprice' but it didn't work. Correct values means in `Iteam Price` only digits are allowed. Problem is that fields are not getting validated

Comment: Try this answer for dynamic name fields and form validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071413/dynamic-form-name-attribute-input-type-text-name-variable-name-in

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$('.form-group').each(function(){
  var input = $(this).children('input');
  if(input.val() == '' || input.val() == undefined){
    // the errors you will give
  }else{
    if(input.attr('id').substring(0, 5) == 'iname'){
      //function to validate your iname
    }else if(input.attr('id').substring(0, 6) == 'iprice'){
      //function to validate your iprice
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can u please add one function to add validate empty field

Comment: For checking empty input, it's in the `foreach` as follows: `if(input.val() == '' || input.val() == undefined){
    // the errors you will give
  }`

Comment: But it is not validating empty fields that are getting added by JQuery

Comment: When are you calling this function?

Comment: i am calling this function click of submit button.. can u write a fiddle for better understanding

Comment: You have to put the function on the form submission. `$('#form').submit(function(){});` then if there is error you prevent the submission..

Comment: if we add `alert("Wrong");` after console.log in name not matching validation, then alert is not coming up. :( Please help